# rails 3.0.3 embedded views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

This question is a direct result of my ignorance to rails, and therefore terrible search queries. I'm trying to place a sortable table on every page of my application. Basically an inventory list needs to show up everywhere. However, on the user's profile page, I get an undefined method `sort_by` error.

Here's how its set up, I've got two helper methods `sort_by` and `sort_direction` in my inventory controller. Then I've got a helper method, in application helper, that creates the link:

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil, css_class = "sort")
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_by ? css_class + " current #{sort_direction}" : css_class
    direction = column == sort_by && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
```

I know my problem is that I'm using `sort_by` and `sort_direction` while on the user controller. But how would I access them through the inventory controller?

Answer (score 0):

Move those two methods to your `ApplicationController`, and add a `helper_method :sort_by, :sort_direction` line to your controller (which will expose those methods to your view as helper methods). All controllers inherit from it, so any methods in there will be available to all controllers, and adding `helper_method` exposes them to all views.

That said, if you aren't using those methods in controller actions, move them into a helper, as well.

Comment: The problem I get when I modularize it like that is a "No route matches" error. Because I'm throwing the sort_by param in the url.

Specifically I tried moving everything to the application_helper.